# HQL query to join 2 tables with the same key

Tags: hql

Iam trying to this in HQL:
select A.a A.a1, B.b,B.b1  from A,B
where A.x=B.x;
It is simple to realize the join with sql but when returninig in HQL I find a problem.
would you please give me the HQL syntax for  the join
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work:

```
select ai.a, ai.a1, bi.b, bi.b1
from A ai, B bi where ai.x = bi.x
```